# Decapitalizing characters in python

Tags: python, arrays, token

For the assignment given to us, we need to take a poem and tokenize it and put it in an array. Then using the map and filter functions we have to depunctuate and decapitalize the poem while putting it in a new array. I have figured out everything up until decapitalizing the poem. With the sample code given to us, it tells us how to decapitalize a character but I need to figure out how to read all of the characters and return a list so it decapitalizes everything. Here is the code that I have so far.

```
def decapitalizeTokens(transformed):
    decap = []
    for i in range(0,len(transformed),1):
       lowered = toLower(transformed[i])
       decap.append(lowered)
       print(lowered)
       return decap

def toLower(ch):
    if (ord(ch) <= ord('Z')):
        return chr(ord(ch) + ord('a') - ord('A'))
    else:
        return ch
```

Comment: That's kind of an odd way to achieve `.lower()` ...

Comment: It was the sample code that our teacher gave us and he said we have to use it. That's why I'm having problems.

Comment: Sounds like your teacher is an idiot.

Comment: Idiot may be a bit harsh, but I agree, there are significantly better ways to teach the concepts for `map` and `filter`.  It's especially unfortunate that he seems to be discouraging the use of built-in functionality - why teach a language, then waste its features?

Comment: +1 at g.d.d.c if you want to teach map/filter use lisp ... if you want to teach python use builtin features and pythons best parts (like list comprehensions).

Comment: @JoranBeasley That's why I never understand questions that say "No imports." This is PYTHON dammit, not Javascript. If I can't import, I'm not writing Python anymore I'm just hacking together some pseudo-code and pretending it's a language. I contend that any question that can't be solved by `import foo` is not a problem worth solving in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Your `decapitalizeTokens` function is actually close to what you want (as far as I can tell), but if you've pasted it *exactly* as you have it in your source file then the issue appears to be that your `return` statement needs to be de-dented one level.  You want to return your list of lowercase characters after your loop has completed, not when you reach the end of its first pass.

```
def decapitalizeTokens(transformed):
    decap = []
    for ch in transformed: # You can iterate directly over a string.
        lowered = toLower(ch)
        decap.append(lowered)
        print(lowered)
    # right here we'll return a list.  ''.join() if you want a string.
    return decap
```

As another form of oneliner, you could use a comprehension:

```
decap = [toLower(ch) for ch in transformed]
```

-- Adding interactive samples --

```
>>> s = 'A test String'
>>> def toLower(ch):
...     if (ord(ch) <= ord('Z')):
...         return chr(ord(ch) + ord('a') - ord('A'))
...     else:
...         return ch
...
>>>
>>> [toLower(c) for c in s]
['a', '@', 't', 'e', 's', 't', '@', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
>>> [toLower(c) for c in '']
[]
>>> map(toLower, s)
['a', '@', 't', 'e', 's', 't', '@', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
>>> toLower('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in toLower
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found
>>>
```

Note that we can iterate over a blank string as effectively as one with characters, and also the odd behavior of your professor's `toLower` function when it is passed a space.

Comment: I just tried to put this in my code and it didn't work.

Comment: @user3295470 - Can you elaborate on "didn't work"?  Tracebacks?  As I look at it the indentation is inconsistent (4 spaces at one level, 3 at another) but that's copied from your code in the question.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "words.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "words.py", line 7, in main
    words = decapitalizeTokens(clean)
  File "/home/Katherine/cs150/project1/shakes.py", line 33, in decapitalizeTokens
    lowered = toLower(ch)
  File "/home/Katherine/cs150/project1/shakes.py", line 38, in toLower
    if (ord(ch) <= ord('Z')):
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found  This is the error I get when running that code.

Comment: @user3295470 - the error you received _cannot_ be caused by code demonstrated here.  See my interactive examples using both `map` and a comprehension.  The _only_ way to produce that error is to pass in a blank string to `ord`, but nothing in your sample or my version would do that.  Please edit the question and verify that the code in your files is represented in your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
"".join(map(toLower,filter(str.isAlpha, a_word)))
```

is that what your looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really ask a question so I will not really answer it- the code you posted has a pretty serious problem though.

If the string you pass in has anything in it other than letters, you will get unintentional behavior.  The string

```
Hi!
```

changes to

```
hiA
```

You need to make sure that the letters you are "lowering" are actually letters and not punctuation.